# Памперсы или подгузники?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Насколько я знаю, "Памперс" - изначально это название популярной фирмы, которые делает подгузники. Однако сейчас слово "подгузник" можно услышать очень редко, все их так и называют "памперсы", причем, речь идет и о детских, и о взрослых.
Хотелось бы узнать, вошло ли в словари слово "памперсы" или все-таки так говорить и писать неграмотно и надо употреблять слово "подгузники"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Памперсы уже попали в словарь.  ***ПАМПЕРСЫ, -ов; мн. [от англ. pamper - изнеживать баловать].
Одноразовые подгузники с особой прокладкой, которая легко впитывает жидкость, оставаясь снаружи сухой. Одеть ребёнку памперс. Всё ещё ходит в памперсах.  Памперсный, -ая, -ое.См. Большой толковый словарь русского языка.***

Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2009 года

Answer (score 0):

"Одеть ребёнку памперс" нельзя.  "Одеть ребёнкА в памперс", может быть, можно. Лучше всего НАДЕТЬ на ребёнка памперс.

Comment: Для замечаний и уточнений используются **_комментарии_**!